# What preprocessing image techniques should I take in consideration before applying OpenCV's Viola-Jones method for face detection?

Tags: c, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection

I am working for a project at school regarding face detection, based on a technique described by Viola and Jones 2001/2004.

I've read that the OpenCV has an implementation of this algorithm, and it works very good.

I was wondering if you have any advices regarding what techniques (pre-processing) to apply to the images before testing the existence of a face (eg. histogram equalization) ?

Comment: Since you're in school, I'll add an entirely academic comment: Viola and Jones is a method for face detection not face recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically used the code from this [sample program](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection) from the OpenCV page and it worked very well for my masters thesis project. If you get bad results or your lighting is strange you can try a histogram equalization.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've managed to create my Viola Jones program using OpenCV. It works well (except it never recognize Obama :)) ). I will try to improve my working code by applying a histogram equalization. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @Janusz Broken link.

Answer (score 1):

with a friend I did something similar too for an university project, and especially on low resolution video sequences it really helped to upsample the frame, doubling its size. It was my friends' idea, who had previously taken an image processing class. Although equivalent, things like decreasing initial scan window size, horizontal and vertical steps didn't produce the same result. In other words it may be better to work on larger images with larger scan windows than on smaller with smaller scan windows. Don't know exactly why.

Bye ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've finished the project, but I'll try out of curiosity :).

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late. But do go through [this](http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html) site as well.

It speaks of the common pre-proccessing required for the images. Equalising the image, Editing irrelevant content etc